# How to add new features to OpenDayLight Karaf?

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, sdn, opendaylight

How can I add new features to ODL Oxygen SR3 (0.8.3) as a Karaf module?

For example, I downloaded the prebuilt ODL from the [official page](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.8.3/karaf-0.8.3.tar.gz). Then I'd like to make the [Toaster sample](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step) as a new module for Oxygen, it was created with command:

```
wget -q -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendaylight/odlparent/master/settings.xml > ~/.m2/settings.xml
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After compiling, it would generate built files to a local maven repository (`~/.m2/repository/com/example/toaster`). I copied the `com/example/toaster` to the Karaf default repository folder `./karaf-0.8.3/system`. Then I'd like to make it available in `feature:list` so I can install with `feature:install toaster`. First I need to add it to the repo list:

```
./karaf-0.8.3/bin/karaf
feature:repo-add mvn:com.example.toaster/features-toaster
```

Unfortunately it showed an error:

> Error executing command: Error resolving artifact com.example.toaster:features-toaster:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>
> [Could not find artifact com.example.toaster:features-toaster:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in opendaylight-snapshot (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/)] : mvn:com.example.toaster/features-toaster

The above command is based on [this post](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/7896/how-to-use-add-repo/). What's the correct way to do `repo-add`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_artifacts_repositories_and_urls
Article. 
What you need to do is basically add the repo URl that contains your toaster to the package like so:
(Example from the documentation linked above)

```
<bundle>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/nmr/org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api/1.0.0-m2/org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api-1.0.0-m2.jar</bundle>
```

Repositories can also be defined using properties:

> org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories : Comma separated list of remote
>   repository URLs that are checked in order of occurence when resolving
>   maven artifacts

Source: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_maven_url_handler

Answer (score 0):

After building change configuration at the end of file `karaf/target/assembly/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` into

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
    file:${karaf.home}/${karaf.default.repository}@id=system.repository, \
    file:${karaf.data}/kar@id=kar.repository@multi, \
    https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot@id=opendaylight-snapshot@snapshots, \
    https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public@id=opendaylight-mirror
```

Then you can add a repository with

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.opendaylight.netconf/features-restconf/1.9.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features
```

where `groudId: org.opendaylight.netconf`, `artifactId: features-restconf` and `version: 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT` are depending on the feature you want to add. You can search at  https://nexus.opendaylight.org/ with `Articfact Search` for them and find them in the Maven pom.