# Procedure to add features to OpenDaylight application

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, opendaylight, blueprint-osgi

This is an inverse of my question [Install a custom feature or module in Opendaylight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060044/install-a-custom-feature-or-module-in-opendaylight). I am looking to take the [Hello World app](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html) and add the ability to do a `feature:install` for the following features:

## feature:install

1. odl-restconf
2. odl-mdsal-apidocs
3. odl-openflowplugin-flow-services
4. odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer
5. odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions
6. odl-restconf-all
7. odl-openflowplugin-flow-services

I assume it comes down to listing these features properly in one of the many pom files.

For the record, currently we run the [ODL 0.12.1](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/opendaylight/0.12.1/) by downloading the .tar.gz from ODL's nexus server, shell into karaf, and run the `feature:install` command against all the above features and I am able to do the install.

I'd like to be able to run that same `feature:install` for all those features as well, but in the Hello World example, karaf can't find those features.

There are some similar questions out there (such as this [How to add new features to OpenDayLight Karaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311946/how-to-add-new-features-to-opendaylight-karaf)) however the answers weren't specific enough and seem generic to Karaf. For example, the answer there seems to be about modifying the values of `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` however when I look at the [ODL 0.12.1 integration/distribution repo](https://github.com/opendaylight/integration-distribution/releases/tag/0.12.1), I do not see this value being used at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the featuresBoot config in the
etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file.

Comment: I actually use the featuresBoot in my ODL 0.12 install to have karaf automatically install features at start up `echo 'featuresBoot = service-wrapper,odl-restconf,odl-mdsal-apidocs,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services,odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer,odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions,odl-restconf-all,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services, 7c502cea-55c3-43dc-984d-402be0837b96' >> /opt/opendaylight/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`

That said, I believe those features need to be available in the first place for that to work?

Comment: yes, that's right. if the features aren't available then being in featuresBoot is meaningless. I think you have another question open about that right? Did you
figure that out yet?

Comment: Kind of, I have a new problem now. I got ODL's Karaf to find my hello world feature, but its giving me trouble during the install. It's honestly a lot to go through in the logs, I don't understand why. I am thinking versions are off between my ODL 0.12.1 and the hello world which is based off of 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.